# Json.net serialize c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

i want to make json like this

```
 {
        'month': '201701',
        'value': '170',
        'target': '100'
    },
    {
        'month': '201702',
        'value': '200',
        'target': '200'
    },
    {
        'month': '201703',
        'value': '210',
        'target': '400'
    }
```

in the newtons documentation is like this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm

i following the documentation but only get

```
{
    'month': '201701',
    'value': '170',
    'target': '100'
}
```

and i try to insert in my loop like this

```
SellTrhu product = new SellTrhu();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
            {
                double[] month = new double[8];
                month[i] = 201700 + i;
                amount[i] = _context.VGetSellThruSales.Where(y => y.Month == month[i]).Select(x => x.NetAmount ?? 0).Sum();
                targetAmount[i] = _context.DashboardSellThruSummary.Where(y => y.Month == month[i]).Select(x => x.Ach ?? 0).Sum();

                product.month = month[i];
                product.value = amount[i];
                product.target = targetAmount[i];
            }
```

but it return error

Comment: Did u add it to a list. It should be a collection of items. Collection of product you need to serialize. Now you might be serializing a single object. You should include the product inside for loop. Then add the product to a list of products and then serialize

Comment: Sample output in the post does not represent valid JSON so you need to build it manually with string concatenation of individual blocks... C# sample is very strange and does not clarify question...

Comment: What error do you get? Also I noticed that you are NOT initializing amount, and targetAmount. Another problem is your product variable will keep getting overwritten for each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
        List<SellTrhu> products = new List<SellTrhu>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            SellTrhu product = new SellTrhu();
            double[] month = new double[8];
            month[i] = 201700 + i;
            amount[i] = _context.VGetSellThruSales.Where(y => y.Month == month[i]).Select(x => x.NetAmount ?? 0).Sum();
            targetAmount[i] = _context.DashboardSellThruSummary.Where(y => y.Month == month[i]).Select(x => x.Ach ?? 0).Sum();

            product.month = month[i];
            product.value = amount[i];
            product.target = targetAmount[i];
            products.Add(product);
        }
```

Now serialize products